# Dropdown list editor in Aurelia Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, aurelia

Here is the dropdown code, which I got from [here](http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/samples/grid/editing-custom-editor):

```
myDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            //var fieldName="";

                $('<input required data-text-field=\"myType\" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:name"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataSource: {
                          data: this.myList
                        }
                    });
        }
```

At runtime, when I click on edit button on the grid, I get the following error:

```
my-type.ts:138 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myList' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in this.myList and it's not undefined like the error suggests?

Comment: @calinaadi yes, I am sure.

Comment: I would say that "this" in that context refers to dataSource which is not created yet and it's undefined.

Comment: try changing `myDropDownEditor(container, options) { ... }` to `myDropDownEditor = (container, options) => { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this,

```
dropdownEditor(container: any, options: any) {
    const dropDownData = [
      { name: 'One', value: 'ValueOne' },
      { name: 'Two' value: 'ValueTwo' },
      { name: 'Three', value: 'ValueThree' }
    ];
    $('<input required data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: 'name',
        dataValueField: 'value',
        dataSource: dropDownData,
        optionLabel: 'Please select'
      });
  }
```